# laravel eloquent - how to select users

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got two tables:

Users table with id's
And Messages table with users's Id as "from" and offer Id's as offer_id

I want to select all users that send messages to with certain offer_id's

For example
user with id 1 send few messages:

```
Id from   offer_id
1. 1,     5
2. 2,     5
3. 1,     5
4. 1,     3
```

I want to select all users that sent offer_id =5, so users of id 1 and 2

How to do it via eloquent with Message and User class?
I've got offer_id given so I can easily select messages:

`$messages = Message::where('offer_id', $id);`

but how to select users?

edit:
I tried this way:
in Message model:

```
public function fromContact()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'from');
}
```

and then in controller:

`$contacts = $messages->fromContact;`

but it gives an error

edit migration:

```
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('from')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('to')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('read')->default(false);
        $table->integer('offer_id')->nullable();
        $table->mediumText('body')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and error:

```
"message": "Undefined property: 
Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::$fromContact",
```

Comment: You should read about [Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships). Then show us what you have tried.

Comment: I've just edited my question

Comment: Also add your migration, and ofcourse, the error you are getting.

Comment: I've just added them

Comment: I did give you an answer simular to @TimLewis, but it was almost a duplicate, so I removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some closure on your Query Builder. When you use

```
$messages = Message::where('offer_id', $id);
```

You don't have an instance of `Message` until you use a Closure, which are `->first()`, `->get()`, etc. So using

```
$message->fromContact;
```

Will result in an error stating that `->fromContact` is not available on a `Builder` instance. To make this work, use

```
$messages = Message::where('offer_id', $id)->get();
foreach($messages AS $message){
  $contacts = $message->fromContact;
}
```

Since this doesn't have much context in a loop, the code above doesn't do anyhting, but `$messages->fromContact` would also be an error. To get around that, use:

```
$message = Message::where('offer_id', $id)->first();
$contacts = $message->fromContact;
```

That should give you a good idea of what's going wrong and how to handle it.

**Edit**

When looping over multiple `Message` instances, push `$message->fromContact` to an array (or `Collection`) for use later:

```
$messages = Message::with(['fromContact'])->where('offer_id', $id)->get(); 
// Note: Using `::with()` prevents additional database calls when using `$message->fromContact` in a loop.

$contacts = []; // or $contacts = collect([]);
foreach($messages AS $message){
   $contacts[] = $message->fromContact; // or $contacts->push($message->fromContact);
}
```

Comment: let me see.. I need some practice, It's so simple mistake

Comment: it gives me: `"message": "Property [fromContact] does not exist on this collection instance."`

Comment: That means that `$message` or `$messages` is a `Collection`, and not a `Message`. Did you read my note about using `->get()` with a loop vs using `->first()`?

Comment: let me try this out :)

Comment: No worries. It'll all start to make sense after you've done this a few hundred (thousand) times; you'll eventually be able to tell at a glance when you have a `Builder` instance, vs a `Collection`, vs a `Message`, etc etc, and what methods are available based on that. Keep asking questions though; it's the best way to learn :)

Comment: It's a little confusing I try this with `->get()` and loop but it gives me only the last record

Comment: If you define `$contacts` in a loop, it'll be available outside of the loop as the last record's `->fromContact`.

Comment: How are you using `$contacts = $message->fromContact`?

Comment: oh it works, I declare `$contacts = array();` and then `foreach($messages as $message){
          $contacts[] = $message->fromContact;
        }`

Comment: There you go. *"not sure if I'm doing it the right way"* is all based on how you plan on using what you're retrieving; so if you need to get a bunch of records and use them later, popping them into an array works :)

Comment: I prefer using resources and then do the job on client site with js ;) but I have to work with raw eloquent for some time ;)

Comment: I cannot accept the answer without the edit with array declaring ;)